# Positions are wrong on devices with RTL layout enabled

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-popup-menu

- react-native 0.51.1
- react alpha-16.0.0
- react-native-popup-menu latest.
- The contexmenu are not correctly rendered on devices with RTL layout enabled.
- please tell me how to fix that.!
  [I clicked here on the edit button nr 43.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2vjB.png)

Comment: what does it mean not correctly rendered?

Comment: Not in right position on the screen , but if i turn rtl support off it works fine.

Comment: wrong (in respect to RTL) or just "totally" wrong? :) screenshot would be the best

Comment: currently popup menu does not support RTL layout, I've created issue for it https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu/issues/65

Comment: Thanks @madox2. I checked out your branch and it works fine.